# How does Opcode decide the keys to the data it caches?

Tags: php, apc, multi-tenant, opcode

I am writing a simple multi tenant system and I want to use opcode caching. 
Lets say I have a single php web application accessed via 100 different domain names.

Will opcode cache the same files 100 times, or just once?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not specifying the opcode cache you intend to use. NB: From PHP 5.5 onwards, you'll be constrained to ZendOptimizer+ anyway.

I am unsure about the answer for eAccellerator and XCache, however for APC and ZendOptimizer+ i can confirm that intermediate code for files executed unter seperate subdomains will only be cached once.

You can confirm this yourself by throwing an control panel script onto your web server (use [ocp.php](https://gist.github.com/ck-on/4959032/?ocp.php) or for APC, use apc.php which is contained in the [APC download](https://pecl.php.net/package/APC)). When calling up your web page from one domain, checking the control panel script from another domain will show additional cached files.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct. Using a control panel script to see the status of what is cached, and then loading pages from several domains that used the same php source code directories, I confirmed this. Loading the same scripts from different domains would not increase the number of scripts cached. I used Opcode, but i do not know the underlying cache.